# Шифрование дириктории/ссылки файла

Tags: php, файлы, ссылки

Как можно шифровать дериктории нахождения файлов,чтобы пользователь сайта не имел прямой доступ к деректориям?
И чтобы ссылка была постоянной,или поставить время через сколько она удаляется. Хочу сделать что то на подобии rghost.ru.
чтоб ссылка выклядела так

```
http://tau.rghost.ru/download/8p9nxsGq2/e51937a018ad81ecadff46b9dbcb1e6dd10458e0/63%20java%20-%20BUTTON.docx
```

А у меня выглядет вот так
ссылка на скачивание

```
www.sayt.ru/uploads/63 java - BUTTON.docx.
```

Comment: Чтобы пользователь не имел прямого доступа к каталогам, их надо закрывать средствами web-сервера, например через .htaccess

Comment: А можно по подробнее,о чём мне нужно прочитать чтобы понять?

Comment: Вам нужно читать документацию на используемый web-сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шифрование директорий делается в .htaccess 
Для запрета доступа ко всем директориям пропиши в файле .htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: Файл .htaccess должен лежать в корне сайта, где например лежит файл index.php

Comment: всё получилось,спасибо... Теперь дериктории скрыты..

Comment: Но у меня по прежнему ссылка выгдядит       www.sayt.ru/uploads/pesnya.mp3 ... А как можно сделать так чтобона была вида www.sayt.ru/uploads/8p9nxsGq2/e51937a018ad81ecadff46b9dbcb1e6dd10458e0/63%20java%20-%20pesnya.mp3